# An evolutionary algorithm written in Java to crack an XOR cipher

Tags: java, programming-challenge, strings, cryptography, genetic-algorithm

Alright. So [TryHackme](https://tryhackme.com) is a website that tries to teach hacking with hands on labs. They have a room called [JVM Reverse Engineering](https://tryhackme.com/room/jvmreverseengineering) where the user gets to reverse engineer Java apps, and in particular the code that I am asking you to review is for task #5.

Task #5 challenges the user to crack a password encrypted with a simple XOR cipher. You can reverse engineer the app yourself, but here are the important bits:

Firstly, their `xor` cipher is defined as the following `String`:

```java
// Decompiled from the task #5 challenge.
private static String xor(String var0) {
  char[] var1 = var0.toCharArray();
  char[] var2 = new char[var1.length];

  for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2.length; ++var3) {
     char var4 = var1[var3];
     var2[var3] = (char)(var4 ^ var3 % 3);
  }

  return new String(var2);
}
```

Secondly, the password is correct if the XOR of the inputted password is equal to the `xor` of the `correctPassword`, which is a string equal to `aRa2lPT6A6gIqm4RE`.

My solution is to use my own modified and applied version of [Dawkins' weasel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program) to "evolve," for lack of a better term, a solution to what the "password" might be. When looking at my code, I would like feedback as to make it better. Here are some things to consider in your feedback:

1. Can I adopt better a coding style?
2. Can I make my code smaller without compromising its ease of reading?
3. Can I optimise my code to make it run quicker?

The following is my code:

````java
/*
 * An application to crack an XOR cipher using Dawkins' weasel
 * By A. S. "Aleksey" Ahmann <hackermaneia@riseup.net>
 * - Githubs: https://github.com/Alekseyyy
 * - TryHackMe: https://tryhackme.com/p/EntropyThot
 *
 * Note that some parts of this programme are borrowed from o-
 * -ther sources. Most notably, the "xor" function that retur-
 * -ns a String is the result of decompiling the .class file
 * of TryHackMe's problem. P1's random string generator is ba-
 * -sed off of the following website:
 * - https://www.baeldung.com/java-random-string
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dawkins {
   private static final String correctPassword = "aRa2lPT6A6gIqm4RE";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random random = new Random();
      int counter = 1;
    
      char[] target = correctPassword.toCharArray();
      char[] solution = new char[target.length];

      System.out.println("==========================================================");
      System.out.println("= A crude, amateurish implementation of Dawkins'          ");
      System.out.println("= weasel to crack the TryHackMe XOR cipher                ");
      System.out.println("= By A. S. \"Aleksey\" Ahmann <hackermaneia@riseup.net>   ");
      System.out.println("= - https://github.com/Alekseyyy                          ");
      System.out.println("= - https://tryhackme.com/p/EntropyThot                   ");
      System.out.println("==========================================================\n");

      boolean done = false;
      while (!done) {
         // [P1] Generate random string (of course the length of random string should = correctPassword)
         // - this "seed" is based off of the following: https://www.baeldung.com/java-random-string
         char[] seed = random.ints(48, 123)
            .filter(k -> (k <= 57 || k >= 65) && (k <= 90 || k >= 97))
            .limit(target.length)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString().toCharArray(); 
         // [P2] Put the random string through the xor cipher, and split it into char array of course
         char[] nextGen = xor(new String(seed)).toCharArray();
         // [P3] Save the matching characters as "offspring"
         boolean emptySlots = false;
         for (int k = 0; k < solution.length; k++) {
            if (solution[k] != Character.MIN_VALUE) {
               continue;
            }
            else {
               emptySlots = true;
               if (nextGen[k] == target[k]) {
                  solution[k] = seed[k];
               }
            }
         }

         System.out.printf("Generation %d: %s\n", counter, new String(solution));
         counter++;
         if (!emptySlots) {
            done = true;
         }
      }

      System.out.printf("Solution: %s\n", new String(solution));
   }

   // From the decompile dump of "BasicStringObfuscation.class"
   private static String xor(String var0) {
      char[] var1 = var0.toCharArray();
      char[] var2 = new char[var1.length];

      for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2.length; ++var3) {
         char var4 = var1[var3];
         var2[var3] = (char)(var4 ^ var3 % 3);
      }

      return new String(var2);
   }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm no Java expert and I may have missed some of the point of the code.

**Last iteration**

When iterating the characters of `solution` to check whether it is valid, we rely on its previous value instead of the one we may possible give it.

Hence, we go through an additional iteration even though we could stop directly.

Here is my suggestion

```
         // [P3] Save the matching characters as "offspring"
         boolean solutionIsValid = true;
         for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i] == Character.MIN_VALUE) {
               if (cipheredSeed[i] == target[i]) {
                  solution[i] = seed[i];
               } else {
                  solutionIsValid = false;
               }
            }
         }
```

I took this chance to:

- get rid of continue
- rename a few things

**Principle**

A lot of time is spent generating random values, ciphering them and checking the ciphered value but most of the characters ciphered and wrong and/or unused.

Because each character is ciphered independenly (otherwise, the whole logic here would fail), it may be faster to progress character by character.

This gives something like:

```
/*
 * An application to crack an XOR cipher using Dawkins' weasel
 * By A. S. "Aleksey" Ahmann <hackermaneia@riseup.net>
 * - Githubs: https://github.com/Alekseyyy
 * - TryHackMe: https://tryhackme.com/p/EntropyThot
 *
 * Note that some parts of this programme are borrowed from o-
 * -ther sources. Most notably, the "xor_str" function that retur-
 * -ns a String is the result of decompiling the .class file
 * of TryHackMe's problem. P1's random string generator is ba-
 * -sed off of the following website:
 * - https://www.baeldung.com/java-random-string
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dawkins {
   private static final String correctPassword = "aRa2lPT6A6gIqm4RE";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[] target = correctPassword.toCharArray();
      char[] solution = new char[target.length];

      System.out.println("==========================================================");
      System.out.println("= A crude, amateurish implementation of Dawkins'          ");
      System.out.println("= weasel to crack the TryHackMe XOR cipher                ");
      System.out.println("= By A. S. \"Aleksey\" Ahmann <hackermaneia@riseup.net>   ");
      System.out.println("= - https://github.com/Alekseyyy                          ");
      System.out.println("= - https://tryhackme.com/p/EntropyThot                   ");
      System.out.println("==========================================================\n");

      for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
         // Loop over candidates
         for (char c = 48; c <= 123; c++) {
             if ((c <= 57 || c >= 65) && (c <= 90 || c >= 97)) {
                 // Check if valid
                 if (xor_c(c, i) == target[i]) {
                     solution[i] = c;
                 }
             }
         }
      }

      // TODO: Handle cases when 0 or many characters are found
      System.out.printf("Solution: %s\n", new String(solution));
   }

   // From the decompile dump of "BasicStringObfuscation.class" and then refactored
   private static char xor_c(char c, int index) {
       return (char)(c ^ index % 3);
   }
   private static String xor_str(String s) {
       char[] input = s.toCharArray();
       char[] output = new char[input.length];
   
       for(int i = 0; i < output.length; ++i) {
           output[i] = xor_c(input[i], i);
       }
       return new String(output);
   }
}
```

Then, if we are ready to take into the actual logic in `xor_c`, we could compute the solution value directly by performing the opposite of the operations. In this particular case, the function to decipher is actually the one used to cipher as well. This idea does not generalize to an arbitrary cipher function.

Comment: Oh gol dang, thanks for dat input :D
I am **not** a Java developer either so that in part explains why my code is a bit rubbish. I already published an article discussing my solution (if the paywall is giving you problems, just view the article in private browsing mode ;-) https://ai.plainenglish.io/a-n-application-of-dawkins-weasel-to-cracking-a-simple-xor-cipher-5459f61dda39

But I will def take your advices into account (esp since I want to rewrite this into something better in the future ;-)